# parameter error in angular 2 component

Tags: angular, typescript

I am getting an error when I add a service to the constructor of a component.  The error is "Can't resolve all parameters for RecordComponent".  Any idea why adding the service to the constructor causes this error?

This is my service

```
//record.service.ts

import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class RecordService {
    getPosts() {
       return 'Hello'; 
    }
}
```

This is the component.  If I comment out the service parameter in the constructor, it works.

```
//record.component.ts

import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { RecordService } from './record.service';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
    selector: 'record-view',
    template: '<h1>This is the record creation page</h1>'
})

export class RecordComponent implements OnInit {
    message: string;

    constructor(private recordService: RecordService, private router: Router) { 

    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.message = this.recordService.getPosts(); 
        console.log(this.message);
    }
}
```

I can post my app.component, main, and app.module if necessary.

EDIT:

Here is my app.module file

```
//app.module.ts

import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { routing } from './app.routing';
import { AdminComponent } from './admin/admin.component';
import { RecordComponent } from './record/record.component';
import { RecordService } from './record/record.service';
import { AppComponent }  from './app.component';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';

@NgModule({
  imports: [ BrowserModule, routing, HttpModule ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent, AdminComponent, RecordComponent ],
  providers: [RecordService],
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})

export class AppModule { }
```

and my app.component file

```
//app.component.ts

import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `
    <h1>Angular 2 App</h1>
    <a routerLink="/admin">Admin</a>
    <a routerLink="/record">Record</a>

    <router-outlet></router-outlet>           `
})
export class AppComponent { }
```

and my main file

```
//main.ts

import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule)
  .then(success => console.log(`Bootstrap success`))
  .catch(error => console.log(error));
```

app.routing file

```
//app.routing.ts

import { ModuleWithProviders } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { AdminComponent } from './admin/admin.component';
import { RecordComponent } from './record/record.component';

const appRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'admin',
    component: AdminComponent
  },
  {
     path: 'record',
     component: RecordComponent
  }
];

export const routing: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes);
```

The complete error I'm seeing is this

```
(index):19 Error: Error: Can't resolve all parameters for RecordComponent: (?, ?).
        at CompileMetadataResolver.getDependenciesMetadata (http://localhost:3000/vendor/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:14381:21)
        at CompileMetadataResolver.getTypeMetadata (http://localhost:3000/vendor/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:14282:28)
        at CompileMetadataResolver.getDirectiveMetadata (http://localhost:3000/vendor/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:14057:30)
        at eval (http://localhost:3000/vendor/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:14461:35)
        at Array.forEach (native)
        at CompileMetadataResolver._getEntryComponentsFromProvider (http://localhost:3000/vendor/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:14460:32)
        at eval (http://localhost:3000/vendor/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:14418:85)
        at Array.forEach (native)
        at CompileMetadataResolver.getProvidersMetadata (http://localhost:3000/vendor/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:14405:21)
        at eval (http://localhost:3000/vendor/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:14412:43)
    Evaluating http://localhost:3000/public/app/main.js
    Error loading http://localhost:3000/public/app/main.js
```

Comment: Did you add `RecordService` into your module's `provider`?

Comment: I will try that @HarryNinh!

Comment: I didn't have it in there but I get the same error after adding it

Comment: Hmm, don't put it in `declarations`, `declarations` is for `component`, `directive` and `pipe` only. I wonder why you didn't receive another error for that.

Comment: Thanks @HarryNinh.  That's good to know.

Comment: Can you post your app.routing file?

Comment: Sure, I've edited the original post to include the app.routing

Comment: Weird, that all looks fine to me.

Comment: One thing that you miss is a RouterModule from @angular/router in your app.module in imports.

Comment: I added the complete error above. Adding the RouterModule still produces the same error.

Comment: Are you sure your typescript is getting transpiled to javascript correctly? Maybe a dumb question but it looks like the typescript is fine.

Answer (score 1):

1) Add RecordService in providers of AppModule like this-

```
providers: [RecordService],
```

2) Import RouterModule in imports property of AppModule like this-

```
imports:      [ BrowserModule, routing, HttpModule, RouterModule ],
```

3) Try changing constructor of RecordComponent like this-

```
constructor( @Inject(RecordService) private recordService: RecordService, private router: Router) {
```

See if this helps.

Comment: Explicitly stating constructor( @Inject(RecordService) private recordService: RecordService...) has helped me.

Comment: @tks423 if its helped you then please marked as useful.

Comment: Do you know why one has to explicitly state constructor( @Inject(RecordService) private recordService: RecordService... I had to do something similar with ActivatedRoute interface in a constructor as well. constructor( @Inject(ActivatedRoute) private route: ActivatedRoute )

Comment: @tks423 I am not sure why we need to explicitly inject sharedservice. With regards to Router, I never explicitly used inject. Routing works as usual.